# Connection Exception fetching large data from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to get some data for the users. The code runs perfectly when the data is small around **5000 rows**. But when i try to fetch data of size **25000 +** rows  the application crashes giving the following Exception with the StackTrace :

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection&#13;
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection&#13;
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:129)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1290)&#13;
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:516)&#13;
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:315)&#13;
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:234)&#13;
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:93)&#13;
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:170)&#13;
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:209)&#13;
        at $Proxy1.getAggregatedFeaturesByCode(Unknown Source)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.session.permissions.PermissionManagerImpl.handleFeatureGroup(PermissionManagerImpl.java:164)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.session.permissions.PermissionManagerImpl.buildUserPermissionMap(PermissionManagerImpl.java:142)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.entity.sql.SqlUser.getUserPermissions(SqlUser.java:2720)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.modules.UsersReport.addResults(UsersReport.java:384)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.modules.UsersReport.gen_main(UsersReport.java:229)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.modules.UsersReport.generate(UsersReport.java:156)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.ShellModule.generateShell(ShellModule.java:2016)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.Application.processRequest(Application.java:1462)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.BCAServlet.performTask(BCAServlet.java:197)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.BCAServlet.doPost(BCAServlet.java:172)&#13;
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)&#13;
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)&#13;
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.session.webservices.axisws.clientactivity.ForceResponseCode200Filter.doFilter(ForceResponseCode200Filter.java:24)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.util.RequestDumperFilter.doFilter(RequestDumperFilter.java:273)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.filters.ReferenceFilter.doFilter(ReferenceFilter.java:57)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.controller.filters.WebContextFilter.doFilter(WebContextFilter.java:60)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at com.ilrn.util.DynamicRequestsFilter.doFilter(DynamicRequestsFilter.java:113)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)&#13;
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)&#13;
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)&#13;
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)&#13;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)&#13;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)&#13;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)&#13;
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)&#13;
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: The driver was unable to create a connection due to an inability to establish the client portion of a socket.

    This is usually caused by a limit on the number of sockets imposed by the operating system. This limit is usually configurable. 

    For Unix-based platforms, see the manual page for the 'ulimit' command. Kernel or system reconfiguration may also be required.

    For Windows-based platforms, see Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 196271 (Q196271).&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1112)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.&lt;init&gt;(MysqlIO.java:344)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ConnectionImpl.java:792)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:377)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)&#13;
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)&#13;
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)&#13;
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:291)&#13;
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:277)&#13;
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:259)&#13;
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:241)&#13;
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)&#13;
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)&#13;
        ... 56 more&#13;
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect&#13;
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)&#13;
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)&#13;
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)&#13;
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)&#13;
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:364)&#13;
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:507)&#13;
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:457)&#13;
        at java.net.Socket.&lt;init&gt;(Socket.java:365)&#13;
        at java.net.Socket.&lt;init&gt;(Socket.java:207)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)&#13;
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.&lt;init&gt;(MysqlIO.java:294)&#13;
        ... 70 more&#13;
```

I have a little clue that the application is trying to make multiple connections and exceeding the limit for number of connections?
DO i need to increase this limit as suggested in the stacktrace itself

`This is usually caused by a limit on the number of sockets imposed by the operating system. This limit is usually configurable.`

If so, how to do that?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a connection pool configured for hibernate (e.g. c3po) ?

Comment: yes.
**hibernate.c3p0.min_size=1**

**hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20**

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace your connection pool is not setup correctly. Note that Hibernate's `ConnectionManager` delegates to Spring's `DriverManagerDataSource`. Its [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) states : _NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool Connections_ . Therefore hibernate may create an excessive amount of connections, violating the OS limit.

Answer (score 2):

increase the max size of your connection pool, and use batch update:

setting the batch size

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
```

and batch update will be something like this :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
int count=0;
while ( customers.next() ) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
    customer.updateStuff(...);
    if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) {
        //flush a batch of updates and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

[reference here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html). If you still get the same problem, post your c3p0 configuration, maybe something wrong there.

Comment: Actually i am not updating the values, i am just pulling the data from database. How will i get help from batch processing(i.e how to get data in batches)

Comment: batch processing is for update(add/edit/delete) only, this will prevent memory leak for too many sql constructed. for select you can use something like `.setFirstResult(int i)` and `.setMaxResults(int n)` instead.